# Раскодировать ссылку из base64

Tags: base64, php

Имеется множество ссылок, подобных этой. Сама ссылка закодирована в base64.

```
<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA%3D%3D" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>
```

Как бы мне сделать так, чтобы она автоматом раскодировала код base64 и код ссылки остался прежним.
Я понимаю, что нужно что-то с этим делать `$url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);`,
но не могу понять, что.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Распарси строки, чтобы получалось так:

    base64_decode('aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA');

Comment: это будет слишком много ручной работы у меня подобных ссылок очень много...
хотелось бы, чтобы оно брало такой код:

    <a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>

а выдавало такой:

    <a href="http://turbobit.net/0djomzvvaa6j.html" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>

Comment: @mixart_2 добавил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

О какой ручной работе вы говорите? Всё ведь предельно просто.

```
$string = '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';
$string .= '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';
$string .= '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';
$string .= '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';

preg_match_all('#<a href="url=(\w+)" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>#', $string, $return);

foreach ($return[1] as $k => $v) {
    $ok = base64_decode($v);
    echo '<a href="'.$ok.'" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a> <br/>';
}
```

Делайте тогда так:

```
$url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
header('Location: http://'.$url);
```

Comment: Я просто не очень в этом разбираюсь...  

    $string = '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';
    $string .= '<a href="url=aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC8wZGpvbXp2dmFhNmouaHRtbA" target="_blank">turbobit.net</a>';

и т.д.

Куда мне это всё вставить?

Comment: @mixart_2, это просто примерные строки, я же не знаю, как ты хранишь свои строки :)

Comment: это php? или что? 
тупой наверно вопрос

Comment: @mixart_2 php это, php

Comment: Это всё равно ручная работа, нужно вылавливать ссылки из html, форматировать под образец охх... ладно тогда, спасибо.

Comment: @mixart_2, всё можно сделать средствами php, но я же не буду за вас писать кучу кода :) я вам дал ответ на вопрос, а дальше дело ваше. Да и в вопросе вы не указывали, как у вас хранятся эти ссылки и что вам точно нужно с ними сделать.


Обновил ответ.

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно всё сделать и что вы не будите за меня писать.  
У меня есть html, в нем много ссылок такого вида:  

    <a href="aHR0cDovL3VsLnRvL3kzejU5bjJj">uploaded.net</a> | <a href="aHR0cDovL3R1cmJvYml0Lm5ldC9kMmMwbnU2a3dua3EuaHRtbA%3D%3D">turbobit.net</a>

Хочется, чтобы всё закодированное декодировалось как можно более автоматизированно. Походу, это целая программа нужна.

Comment: Прикольно, php не требует знаки равенства в конце?